# How to have a value passed to scope from outside the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am new to angular world and I have function which is loading the html inside perticular div on load and then controller gets initialize. I want to make single var available inside the controller so wondering if it's possible to assign that var to scope from outside the controller.

```
//controller 
var cntlrs = angular.module('MyModule');

cntlrs.controller('ControllerTest', function ($scope, $http) {
    //want to have var available here from $scope   
});


//accessing scope from outside
var appElmt = document.querySelector('[ng-app=MyApp]');
var $scope = angular.element(appElmt).scope();
var customer = "New Customer";

//how can I set customer value inside scope?
```

Comment: The variable i want to access is not part of the model. Is it possible to have it there?

Comment: Could you post your html and/or create a plunkr or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the angular docs more. $scope is your model (or probably the term ViewModel is more appropriate).

To get values into your controller, I would recommend a factory or a service. One can call setCustomer on the factory, then other controllers would be able to see that value using getCustomer.

```
var mod = angular.module('MyModule', []);

mod.factory("CustomerFactory", function () {
    var customer;
    return {
        getCustomer: function () {
            return custData;
        }
        setCustomer: function (custData) {
            customer = custData;
        }
    }
});

mod.controller("TestController", function ($scope, $http, CustomerFactory) {
    $scope.customer = CustomerFactory.getCustomer();
}
```

It might also be better if you weren't referencing $scope outside of angular (i.e. from angular.element(...).scope()). I don't know what you are trying to solve, but it seems like from the code above, all that logic can be put inside the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from outside the controller you can target an element that is within your angular controller:

```
var scope = angular.element("#YourElementID").scope();
```

And now you will have access to everything on the `scope` (Just as if you were using `$scope`)

Comment: yes but how can assign new var and value from there?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to work like this, and it seems to be allright!! It does not require a big effort, the only boring part is that in the template you need always to use `vars.somepropertyormethod`

```
//an outside var that keeps all the vars I want in my scope
var vars = {
    val1: 1,
    val2: "dsfsdf",
    val3: function() {return true;}
}


//and here I set the controller's scope to have ONLY vars and nothing else:
angular.module('myModule', [])
    .controller('myControllerOpenToTheWorld', function($scope) { 
        $scope.vars = vars; 
    });
```

With this, I can set `vars.anyproperty` from anywhere I want. The trick is that the real values are all wrapped inside an object, so as long as you don't reassign the wrapper `vars`, you can access it from both outside and inside:

```
//change val2
vars.val2 = "new value changed from outside";
```

In the markup, it would work like this:

```
<div>{{vars.val1}}</div>
<div ng-if:"vars.val3()">{{vars.val2}}</div>
```